# AppleScript Overwrite or Skip Command?

Tags: applescript, finder

I have the following applescript that takes files and puts them in their corresponding folders.

```
set sourceFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder"
set theFiles to files of sourceFolder

repeat with aFile in theFiles
    set fileName to name of aFile

    if fileName contains "#" then
        set poundOffset to offset of "#" in fileName
        set folderName to text 1 thru (poundOffset - 2) of fileName

        set newFolder to (sourceFolder as text) & folderName & ":"
        if not (exists folder newFolder) then
            make new folder at sourceFolder with properties {name:folderName}
        end if

        move aFile to folder newFolder
    end if
end repeat
```

end tell

It works great for me except in the case of a file conflict. If there's a file with the same name in the folder that it's putting it in the script gets an error and crashes. So my question is this....How do I fix that? I'm willing for it to just overwrite the file but is there a way to bring up a prompt to skip the file or just skip it all together and move on to the next one?

I'm a little fuzzy on what I can do here. Thanks in advance for the help.

Ringslinger.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
move aFile to folder newFolder replacing true
```